# git diff changes with name only is showing changes correctly, but not including the files changed in the commit started from

Tags: git

I have a few commits done since midnight

lets say I have the following commits (pretend change23 etc is the SHA commit hash):

change22 (too early, do not want to include changes)

change23

change24

change25

change26

change27 (currently master branch most up to date with everything committed)

So what I want is

`git diff --name-only change23..master`

so I can get all the files changed from change23, 24, 25, 26, and 27 (i.e. since midnight)

and that works great, but it isnt including ALSO the files changed in `change23` its only including files changed in 24, 25, 26, and 27

am I missing a concept?

I can do

`git diff --name-only change23~1..master`

and the `~1` works to include the changes also in change23, but I dont understand this perfectly and am scared ill miss something due to not understanding the ancestor and parent concepts.

Note these are alllllll on the master branch. No other branches are in question

Answer (score 3):

`a..z` does not mean "all the commits from a to z". It is a shorthand for `^a z` meaning "all the commits reachable by z which are not reachable by a". Why?

Git history is not linear. `git log` will lie to you and make it look linear, but it isn't. `git log --graph --decorate` will give you the true history. Branches really branch. There's no clear "between" two commits, so Git uses set theory.

Consider this branch and merge.

```
z
|
y     <----- merge
|\
x \
|  |
w  c
|  |
v  b
| /
|/
a      <---- branch
|
d
```

Remember that commits can only see their parents. z sees y. y sees x and c.

If you ask for `c..z` you'll get z, y, x, w, v. No b and no a and no d, they are reachable from c. And no c, c is reachable from c.

If you ask for `a..z` you'll get z, y, c, b, x, w, v. No a, its reachable from itself. No d, it's reachable from a.

That's why `a^..z` is basically "all the commits between a and z", but it's really "all the commits reachable by z, and not reachable by the first parent of a".

See [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) and [Revision Selection in Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) for more.

Comment: Also worth mentioning though: `git diff` has special code to handle `git diff old..new` that turns it into just plain `git diff old new`. Using `git diff old~..new` just means `git diff old~ new`. The two-dot syntax has the meaning described above for `git log`, and for many other Git commands; but for `git diff`, Git basically just replaces them with one space, and then diffs the two named revisions.

Answer (score 1):

Change your source to change23~ to start from the parent of change23.  It won’t list changes in change23 because that is your base tree essentially.  If it didn’t change from change23 it isn’t a change, otherwise it would just list literally every file in the git repo.

You can also start from change22 to get what you want, as you want to include the changes in change23, it would mean changes since change22

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much
`git diff --name-only change23~..master`

Comment: @CotyEmbry better get used to `git diff change23~ master`. The `..` syntax for the diff subcommand is deprecated and not recommended. It might get removed in the future.